# How to connect Entity Framework with Azure user assigned identity? Instead of using connection string

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework, azure-sql-database, asp.net-identity

Microsoft has given documentation on how to connect through managed identity. it's okay for Azure AD user but I want to use User assigned identity which I've created in Azure portal.

```
var conn = (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)Database.Connection;
var credential = new Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential();
var token = credential.GetToken(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" }));
conn.AccessToken = token.Token;
```

Code provided by Microsoft for creating connection with default Azure credential.

It was working with system assigned identity. Getting error while making connection for user assigned identity.

Comment: Could you please provide the error which you are getting?

Comment: what's the documentation? what's the code? what's the error? make it easy for people to help you and you'll get better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When connecting to an SQL server you basically have 2 options:

1. Connect based on the identity of the calling process
2. Connect based on the information in a connection string

It looks like what you want to do is:

1. Connect using a user assigned identity
2. Do not place user name and password in the connection string

To do this you must:

1. Grant the user assigned identity access to SQL Server
2. Change the identity of the process running your code to the user assigned identity

Comment: Exactly thank you I had missed the granting the access to SQL Server for user assigned identity. now it's working fine.